How to Regex InnnerHTML value to input text from copied InnerHTML Value to input text?
How to remove leading zero and kg from copied innerHTML to input field text?
from 0000300kg to 300?

Html
<button class="tmbltimbang" id="timbangmuatan" onclick="bruto()">BRUTO</button>
<button class="tmbltimbang" id="timbangkosong" onclick="tara()">TARA</button>

BRUTO <input readonly type="text" name="25" id="25" value=""></input>
TARA<input readonly type="text" name="35" id="35" value=""></input>

JS
function bruto() {
    document.getElementById("25").value = document.getElementById("serialResults").innerHTML;
};
enter code here
function tara() {
    document.getElementById("35").value = document.getElementById("serialResults").innerHTML;
};


Please don't delete and ask the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79274262/remove-leading-zeros-data-from-serial-port-by-javascript-jquery

You can use regx: /^0+/ to remove unnecessary zero. I will provide sample code.


function bruto() {
    var value = document.getElementById("serialResults").innerHTML;

    // Remove zeros and kg
    var result = value.replace(/^0+/, '').replace('kg', '');
    document.getElementById("25").value = result;
}

function tara() {
    var value = document.getElementById("serialResults").innerHTML;

    // Remove zeros and kg
    var result = value.replace(/^0+/, '').replace('kg', '');
    document.getElementById("35").value = result;
}
<div id="serialResults">0000300kg</div>

<button class="tmbltimbang" id="timbangmuatan" onclick="bruto()">BRUTO</button>
<button class="tmbltimbang" id="timbangkosong" onclick="tara()">TARA</button>

BRUTO <input readonly type="text" name="25" id="25" value=""></input>
TARA <input readonly type="text" name="35" id="35" value=""></input>




thank you very much. this is what I'm looking for.
awesome!

man... how to auto calculate two input above bruto-tara to another value after click button id="timbangkosong"?

or example Simulate keyup event when data pasted into input box bruto and tara...

Oh... I don't understand well. you mean, when you copy and paste data into BRUTO input box, you want to paste same data into TARA input box??

if bruto 300kg. tara 200kg. then auto calculated netto = bruto-tara. neto=100kg.

[link] (https://ibb.co.com/mDSqMRw)
If I click bruto and tara button, it's not auto calculated in netto field.

if I input manual bruto and tara field, its auto calculation.
[link] (https://ibb.co.com/xY2WGpv)
I want make auto calculation bruto-tara=neto.
so I can make bruto, tara and neto fields readonly without user edit.
